# How do I compile a Python zipapp as optimized?

Tags: python, zipapp

Assume the following code under `src/app.py`:

```
def main():
    assert False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Running this using `python -o src/app.py` will work fine as the assertions are disabled.

How can I package a [zipapp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipapp.html) (`python -m zipapp src -m "app:main"`) such that when it is double-clicked or run, it'll automatically run as optimized?

I've tried changing the extension to `.pyo` and it still resulted in an `AssertionError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I would try the [`--python=<interpreter>`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipapp.html#cmdoption-zipapp-p) option in order to write a [shebang](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#arguments-in-shebang-lines) that contains the options you want (maybe `python -O`). It is somewhat unclear if writing options in the shebang is really supported or not (kind of related [discussion here](https://discuss.python.org/t/packaging-console-scripts-with-interpreter-options/23842/)).

You could also check if [*pex*](https://pypi.org/project/pex/) or [*shiv*](https://pypi.org/project/shiv/) have options for what you want.

Comment: Per your suggestion, I looked at the shebang and [this](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#arguments-in-shebang-lines) seems to be exactly what I need. I'm not sure why does the discussion say otherwise. Yet to test if it actually work (I fear that escaping the quotes would be an issue, i.e. how to differentiate between `"python -o"` as interpreter name vs name+arguments), but I would modify your answer to accompany that link :-)

Comment: Seen from the point of view of your use case, the issue seems to be that there is no specification for *shebangs* (say for example in POSIX). The implementations on most common systems seems to be largely that something like `#!python -O` (maybe even `!#/usr/bin/en python -O`) will behave as one can expect, but it is not strictly guaranteed, there is a small leap of faith to be made. -- The documentation you linked is for the `py` launcher on Windows, which appears to have been designed to mimick the Linux/UNIX behavior. -- All in all it seems to be a reasonably viable solution.

Comment: thank you for your detailed response, I highly appreciate it. I will mark the question as answered as soon as I test and see that it works :-)